# What is the proper way to use Dispatcher.RunAsync() to start a task and return immediately?

Tags: c#, uwp

```
Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    //do something
});
```

The above code causes [Compiler Warning (level 1) CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS4014)):

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method
> continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the await
> operator to the result of the call.

The behavior is exactly what I want: start the task and let it run in a separate thread and return immediately.

I can make the warning go away by changing the code to the following:

```
var v = Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    //do something
});
```

I think "var v" is redundant.  Why is the compiler happy with this redundancy?

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: The warning is telling you that you are doing a _fire and forget_ operation, and truly just forgetting that you _fired_ something.  If you assign the result to `v`, then you at least have a record of what you did.  You can check to see if it completed, for example.  If you really just want fire and forget behavior, suppress the warning for that operation

Comment: Thank you for the elucidation. I was expecting a similar warning by the same token: v is created but never used, so it is either redundant or forgotten to be used.

Comment: You don't get a CS0219 warning (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0219): "The variable 'v' is assigned but its value is never used"?  Maybe you are suppressing that one.

Comment: A little addition that this is a case where you could use a discard: `_ = Dispatcher.RunAsync()`. That way you don't have the hint about an unused variable, while also communicating that you're deliberately fire and forgetting the Task.

Comment: @Flydog57 No, I do not get a warning with squiggles.

Comment: @Knoop thank you for the tip.  I have just adopted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the compiler happy with this redundancy?

Because it uses a very simple heuristic.  It doesn't do an in-depth analysis of the entire program to determine if every code path (or any code path) observes the results of the `Task`.  The warning is *only* triggered by the return value of the Task-returning method (in an `async` method) not ever being stored or accessed.  The main idea here is to prevent someone from calling a method *that they don't even realize is asynchronous* and *unintentionally* ignoring the result.  Intentionally ignoring the result isn't something it's trying to prevent.